# The culture name does not change in the url after change language in ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, localization, asp.net-core-2.1

I follow the https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-localization-deep-dive tutorial to add a language switch for my application.

My problem is, that the culture name not changing in the browser URL after I switch to another language with the select box.

Step by step:

- I run the application, its open in default hungarian language (hu-HU)
- I change the language with the select box to English and the content of the page changes to english, but in the browser url I see /hu-HU/ again. It's not changing to '/en-US/'.

My purged code:

Startup.cs

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        #region Cookies
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        #endregion

        #region Localization
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "");
        services.TryAddSingleton<IStringLocalizer, ZLocalizer>();
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
        options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
               new CultureInfo("en-US"),
               new CultureInfo("hu-HU"),
            };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "hu-HU", uiCulture: "hu-HU");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            services.AddSingleton(options);
        });
        #endregion

        services.AddMvc()
        #region Localization
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o =>
            {
                o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                {
                    return factory.Create(typeof(SharedResources));
                };
            })
        #endregion
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env )
    {
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        #region Multilanguage
        var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions.Value);
        #endregion

        // Multilanguage and culture injection around UseMvc
        app.UseRouter(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=hu-HU}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
            {
                #region Multilanguage
                subApp.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions.Value);
                #endregion

                subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
                {
                    mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                        name: "hidehome",
                        template: "{culture=hu-HU}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home" }
                        );

                    mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{culture=hu-HU}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Partial View

```
@using System.Globalization;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;

@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOps

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOps.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
}

<div title="@Lang["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home"
          asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path"
          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        @Lang["Language:"] <select name="culture"
                                        onchange="this.form.submit();"
                                        asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems"></select>
    </form>
</div>
```

HomeController

```cs
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                new CookieOptions {
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
                    //IsEssential = true,  //critical settings to apply new culture 
                    //Path = "/",
                    //HttpOnly = false,
                }
            );

            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
```

[image]

Where is the problem? Thank you for help!

Comment: Article author here: I guess you'll need to actually go to the other URL, it won't change it for you.

Comment: Ok, but if I navigate to any other link (anchor tag, button) the default language ('hu-HU') will be appear in the browser link and the page content will be english. I donk know how can I go forward with this. This is not simply a routing problem?

Comment: Or maybe you have to specify the culture in every link? I'm just thinking it's not picking it up automatically (though it would be better if it would)

Comment: I would be surprised if it could not be automated.